# how to publish a page using node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, nedb

I have just begun to learn node.js. Over the last two days, I've been working on a project that accepts userinput and publishes a ICS file. I have all of that working. Now consider when I have to show this data. I get a `router.get` to see if I am at the `/cal` page and..

```
router.get('/cal', function(req, res, next) 
    {

        var db = req.db;
        var ical = new icalendar.iCalendar();
        db.find({
            evauthor: 'mykey'
        }, function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(obj) {
                 var event2 = ical.addComponent('VEVENT');
                 event2.setSummary(obj.evics.evtitle);
                 event2.setDate(new Date(obj.evics.evdatestart), new Date(obj.evics.evdateend));
                 event2.setLocation(obj.evics.evlocation)
                 //console.log(ical.toString());
            });
        });

        res.send(ical.toString());
        // res.render('index', {
        //  title: 'Cal View'
        // })
    })
```

So when `/cal` is requested, it loops through my db and creates an ICS calendar `ical`. If I do `console.log(ical.toString)` **within the loop,** it gives me a properly formatted calendar following the protocol.

However, I'd like to END the response with this. At the end I do a `res.send` just to see what gets published on the page. This is what gets published

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR VERSION:2.0 
PRODID:calendar//EN 
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now the reason is pretty **obvious**. Its the nature of node.js. The response gets sent to the browser before the callback function finishes adding each individual `VEVENT` to the calendar object.

I have two related questions:

1) Whats the proper way to "wait" till the callback is done.

2) How
    do I use `res` to send out a .ics dynamic link with
    `ical.toString()` as the content. Do I need to create a new view for
    this ?

edit: I guess for number 2 I'd have to set the HTTP headers like so

```
//set correct content-type-header
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
```

but how do I do this when using views.

Comment: This is mongodb and express, right?

Comment: It's express and `nedb` which is a flatflat NoSQL store I found on github - their github page does say that its a subset of Mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [`send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) the response, once you got the neccessary data! You are not required to `end` or `send` directly in your route but can do it in a nested callback as well:

```
router.get('/cal', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var ical = new icalendar.iCalendar();

    db.find({
        evauthor: 'mykey'
    }, function(err, docs) {
        docs.forEach(function(obj) {
            var event2 = ical.addComponent('VEVENT');
            event2.setSummary(obj.evics.evtitle);
            event2.setDate(new Date(obj.evics.evdatestart), new Date(obj.evics.evdateend));
            event2.setLocation(obj.evics.evlocation)
        });

        res.type('ics');
        res.send(ical.toString());
    });
});
```

I also included sending the proper `Content-Type` by using [`res.type`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.type).

Also: Don't forget to add proper error handling. You can for example use [`res.sendStatus(500)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendStatus) if an error occured while retrieving the documents.

Comment: Ahh that was simple. I did not think about that. I am still getting used to the async callback methods. My last time programming general applications was back in the .net 2.0 days!